# Outputting User Input (CGI)

Tags: perl, cgi

My assignment calls for me to output a range of numbers from highest to lowest but it must be from the user input. Where I'm confused is that I know how to display an array, however, I'm unsure if I'm starting my code off right by using a for loop.

**Assignment**
Create a CGI application with an HTML page named myform.html and a CGI script named myscript.cgi. The HTML page's form has two textboxes for entering the upper and lower values for a range of consecutive integers. Complete the form by choosing values that differ by about 10. Submitting the form should execute myscript.cgi. The script should output an unordered list showing all of the integers in the range from highest to lowest.

```
#!c:\Dwimperl\perl\bin\perl.exe

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

#read form input from user
my $userinput = <STDIN>;
my $low = param ('lowest');
my $high = param ('highest');


foreach (my $userinput < 100){
print "$low && $high" ;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code

```
foreach (my $userinput < 100){
print "$low && $high" ;}
```

With this, doing a for loop counting down from the high number to the low number

```
print qq{<ul>\n};
for (my $i=$high; $i>= $low; $i--) {
    print qq{    <li>$i</li>\n};
}
print qq{</ul>\n};
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't like using the C style loop.  I find it too messy.

Here's is how I'd write it.

```
say "\t<li>$_<\li>" for (reverse $low .. $high);
```

or

```
print "\t<li>$_<\li>\n" for (reverse $low .. $high);
```

Comment: `for my $i (reverse $low .. $high)` will use far more memory than `for (my $i=$high; $i>= $low; $i--)`. This may or may not be a concern for the OP and other readers.

Comment: Also note that the for/foreach statement modifier does not have parens around the expression. `... for reverse $low .. $high;` is perfectly fine.